# How can I obtain and show the version number of an android apk?

Tags: android, apk

In Xcode I do this:

```
NSString *temp;
temp = [@"© 2011 Robert Schoenburg "stringByAppendingString:@"Version "];
temp = [temp stringByAppendingString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]];
myLabel.text = temp;
```

How can I do the same thing in an android app?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getPackageInfo` method from `PackageManager` (which can be obtained via `getPackageManager` method of any `Context`). In the resulting `PackageInfo`, there are `versionCode` and `versionName` fields to read from. They correspond to values set in the *AndroidManifest.xml* in `<manifest>` tag.

EDIT: Added example for obtaining version code/name of own .apk:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
try {
    PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    Log.d("Version " + pi.versionName + "(" + pi.versionCode + ")");
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // impossible here as we refer to our own package
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = m.getPackageInfo("com.mypackage.name", 0);
Log.i("Version Code",info.versionCode+"");
```

Comment: I used the code above and Eclipse reported some errors which I fixed. Here is the working code. I am not seeing the output.